# Draw Loading circle in PyQt

Tags: pyqt

Is there a simple way to draw a loading circle / busy circle in a QDialog or should I just include an animated  .gif image for this purpose?

[image]

Comment: http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_QML_Tutorial_Basic_3 With qml it can be easier

Comment: Is there a reason why you would be doing this? Can't you just set the cursor to "loading" state?